# How to use adb to launch an app and select a menu inside the app?

Tags: android, adb

I am able to launch the Windmill app using adb, the command used was as follows:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.allego.windmill/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity
```

Once the app launches, I get a menu that has "Run Demo", "Run Benchmark" and "About"

How can I select "Run Demo" or "Run Benchmark" without having to use the touchscreen or any other buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know display coordinates of the control you want to interact with you can use `input tap <x> <y>` command to click it.

Or you can use `input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN` to scroll down to the menu item and then `input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER` to select it.

The `input` command has the following options:

```
usage: input ...
   input text <string> [delay]
   input keyevent <key code number or name>
   input [touchscreen|touchpad] tap <x> <y>
   input [touchscreen|touchpad] swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2>
   input trackball press
   input trackball roll <dx> <dy>
```

Comment: This could work! I will try this out. Do you think if I keep logcat running and use the touchscreen to make the selection, it will spit out the display coordinates?

Comment: Actually i was able to find the pointer location using Settings -> Developer options -> Pointer location

Answer (score 1):

As of Unity 4.3 the activity to start has changed:

the command I use to start my Unity application is:

```
adb shell am start -n com.MyCompany.MyProject/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity
```